# Looking for a simple solution to distribute an internal NuGet package

Tags: .net, nuget

I have an internal utility library that is consumed by multiple other solutions. Recently, the utility library was compiled on .NET Framework 4.8. I was then able to copy the DLL over to those other solutions and use them in both Framework and in .NET Core projects.

I'd like to use .NET Core APIs in that utility library so I have converted it to use multitargeting. This worked fine.

Now I wonder how I can best distribute the library to the consuming solutions. The same solution contains both Framework and Core projects consuming the library. This means that I now need two different DLLs where previously a single DLL was sufficient.

I came up with two possible solutions:

1. Copy both versions of the DLL and reference it selectively. This seems tedious.
2. Create an internal NuGet package. Here, I'm not sure how I can reference that package. I want to check the package into source control so a copy of the package has to exist in the consuming solution folder. Another problem is that someone checking out the solution has to configure a local source in the Visual Studio settings. The solution is then no longer self-contained. Also, if you check out the solution twice or change its path, you have to add another source. That does not seem like a good workflow. Another annoyance is that anytime the library changes I need to increment its versions so that NuGet understands that it needs to update. I then need to run package restore to propagate the changes. Currently, the library is always at version `1.0` and that works fine. I just copy over the new DLL and that's as simple as it can be.

I'd be happy to receive some advice. I'm hoping that there is a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own NuGet feed and publish your package to it, which is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds

You can then consume it via `PackageReference` and you should never need to copy dlls around manually.

You also don't want to check the package into source control - you keep the source in source control, and just publish the package to your local feed folder.

For automated package versioning check out https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning